# Multisampled FBO's in OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, fbo, multisampling

How is it possible to have a multisampled texture as part of an FBO in OpenGL ES 3.0 (Android)?

The method `glTexImage2DMultisample` does not seem to exist.

I also want to call `glReadPixels` on this texture later on in this code, 
so the multisampled texture should also be readable.

Is there some kind of extension or utility I would need to use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `glTexStorage2DMultisample`. In general writing multisampled data back to memory is expensive, and needs a resolve using `glBlitFramebuffer` to consolidate to a single sample.

Consider using this extension to get a "free" resolve on most tile-based architectures.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture.txt

Comment: I know I need to use glTexImage2DMultisample, but it doesn't seem to exist in the android environment. My question was how I would get it to work in android? Is there a specific way to import that extension in android?

Comment: glTexImage2DMultisample only exists in OpenGL, it doesn't exist in OpenGL ES at all. So, you really do want to use glTexStorage2DMultisample - it's the only option you have.

Comment: So, is there a way I can accomplish this in OpenGL ES, or are there any alternatives that would provide the same result?

Comment: Why do you think glTexStorage2DMultisample doesn't do what you want? It's pretty much the as as glTexImage2DMultisample ... just with a different name.

Comment: Oh, I misread the function name, sorry about that. I see what you are saying now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, opengl es not support for texture multisampling, glTexStorage2DMultisample not work for texture multisampling. opengl es only support renderbuffer for multisampling, in my case, I resolved multisampling by create a renderbuffer, works charm.

how I did this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    LOGI("ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!");
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

then render:

```
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
 glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight, 0, 0, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight,
                      GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

this works in opengl es 3.2, Android platform.